# java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error upon webservice call

Tags: java, certificate, wifi, ethernet

I have added a server cert on my machine and trying to make a webservice call to server through a java program.

If I run the java application while connected to ethernet, I am able to get appropriate response. But If I run it when connected to Wi-Fi, I am getting Certificate chaining error. Both the ethernet and wi-fi belongs to my company network.

Is there a generic reason for this difference?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference...there must be something else going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause here, when importing the server cert from browser, the "issued by" in "view certificate" is changing as per network. Which is why, If I add only one cert among the below to trust store, the chaining error is showing for other network! But I still don't know why is the "issued by" is changing ethernet vs wifi?

connected to ethernet- the cert "issued by" is xx01

connected to wifi- the cert "issued by" is xx02.

Answer (score 0):

I too say, There should not be any problem with  network change. I request to  validate same with SOAPUI By adding your certificate and send us logs if you see any error.

How to add certificate in soapui you can find here 
{https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/projects/requests/ssl.html}

Answer (score 0):

The most generic difference is wi-fi and ethernet will have different ip addresses, so look for the issues along those lines.